# Filtering By Date Among "Related articles" in Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar

As seen in the below screen shot, the "Related articles" page does not provide the items that permit one to filter only for articles that meet some date criterion.  How can one achieve the desired result of filtering related articles according to some date criterion?
[image]

Comment: Is it even clear that that is possible?

Comment: It's not clear but since there is a years menu presented by default for other searches, I thought perhaps there was a feature hidden somewhere like an advanced search or some sort of search modifiers I was missing.

Comment: Related answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67295/google-scholar-sort-by-date-returns-articles-from-last-year-only